# Один из div’ов уплывает в браузерах на iOS

Tags: html, css

Есть textarea и справа от него div, заполняемый другими div’ами. В Chrome на ПК всё отлично (и в предпросмотре с настройками iPad в режиме разработчика), а в браузерах на iOS второй div (правый который) явно путает берега, равняясь почему-то на вложенные в него элементы относительно края textarea. Что с ним не так?

```css
.ch {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.ch-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%;
    height:60%;
}

.closech {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.closech:hover,
.closech:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea, input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

.chattext {
  width:75%;
  height:70%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:ghostwhite;
  display:inline-block;
}

.ulist {
  width:15%;
  height:70%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:oldlace;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id='ch' class='ch' >
    <div class='ch-content'>
        <span class='closech'>&times;</span>
        <label>Example:</label>
        <div class="chattext"></div><div class="ulist"><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании `inline-block` всегда указывай явно `vertical-align`

```css
.ch {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.ch-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 60%;
    height:60%;
}

.closech {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.closech:hover,
.closech:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea, input {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-indent: -15px;
}

.chattext {
  width:75%;
  height:70%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:ghostwhite;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: top /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
}

.ulist {
  width:15%;
  height:70%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:oldlace;
  display:inline-block;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align: top /* <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< */
}
```

```html
<div id='ch' class='ch' >
    <div class='ch-content'>
        <span class='closech'>&times;</span>
        <label>Example:</label>
        <div class="chattext"></div><div class="ulist"><div>TEST</div><div>TEST</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```